# Removing similar elements but leaving unique ones by looping

Tags: python

I have to remove similar elements from a list which is not sorted, looks like this.

```
[(579, 271, 97, 114), (580, 271, 97, 114), (578, 272, 97, 114), (579, 272, 97, 114), (580, 272, 97, 114), (581, 272, 97, 114), (577, 273, 97, 114), (578, 273, 97, 114), (579, 273, 97, 114), (580, 273, 97, 114), (581, 273, 97, 114), (582, 273, 97, 114), (577, 274, 97, 114), (578, 274, 97, 114), (579, 274, 97, 114), (580, 274, 97, 114), (581, 274, 97, 114), (582, 274, 97, 114), (577, 275, 97, 114), (578, 275, 97, 114), (579, 275, 97, 114), (580, 275, 97, 114), (581, 275, 97, 114), (578, 276, 97, 114), (579, 276, 97, 114), (580, 276, 97, 114), (581, 276, 97, 114), (579, 277, 97, 114), (22, 460, 97, 114), (23, 460, 97, 114), (133, 460, 97, 114), (134, 460, 97, 114), (21, 461, 97, 114), (22, 461, 97, 114), (23, 461, 97, 114), (24, 461, 97, 114), (132, 461, 97, 114), (133, 461, 97, 114), (134, 461, 97, 114), (135, 461, 97, 114), (20, 462, 97, 114), (21, 462, 97, 114), (22, 462, 97, 114), (23, 462, 97, 114), (24, 462, 97, 114), (131, 462, 97, 114), (132, 462, 97, 114), (133, 462, 97, 114), (134, 462, 97, 114), (135, 462, 97, 114), (136, 462, 97, 114), (20, 463, 97, 114), (21, 463, 97, 114), (22, 463, 97, 114), (23, 463, 97, 114), (24, 463, 97, 114), (131, 463, 97, 114), (132, 463, 97, 114), (133, 463, 97, 114), (134, 463, 97, 114), (135, 463, 97, 114), (136, 463, 97, 114), (20, 464, 97, 114), (21, 464, 97, 114), (22, 464, 97, 114), (23, 464, 97, 114), (24, 464, 97, 114), (131, 464, 97, 114), (132, 464, 97, 114), (133, 464, 97, 114), (134, 464, 97, 114), (135, 464, 97, 114), (136, 464, 97, 114), (21, 465, 97, 114), (22, 465, 97, 114), (23, 465, 97, 114), (132, 465, 97, 114), (133, 465, 97, 114), (134, 465, 97, 114), (135, 465, 97, 114), (22, 466, 97, 114), (133, 466, 97, 114), (134, 466, 97, 114)]
```

i want to leave unique elements from comes up first in the head, but remove elements within the difference of 5.

I've coded a function compare difference between each element, but it keeps getting large.

```
def compare_remove(input_list):
    cnt = 0
    glob_cnt = 0
    output_list = [input_list[0]]

    while True:

        for i in range(len(input_list)):
            if i <= cnt:
                print 'jump || '
                continue

            if abs(output_list[cnt][0] - input_list[i][0]) <= 5:
                if abs(output_list[cnt][0] - input_list[i][0]) == 0:
                    continue

                print 'skip ||' + str(output_list[cnt]) +' || ' + str(input_list[i])
                continue
            else:
                print 'append || ' + str(input_list[i])
                output_list.append(input_list[i])

        print 'loop out || '
        input_list = output_list
        cnt+=1

        if cnt == 100:
            break
        try:
            output_list[cnt]
        except:
            break

    return output_list
```

it compares the first element of elements, and the difference between previous one, remove it.

Comment: What is your expected output? What does a difference of `5` mean - it looks like you are just comparing the first element.

Comment: As @AChampion asked, what is "a difference of 5"? Give some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question, but here is the code that leaves unique elements from comes up first in the head, but removes elements within the difference of 5.

```
input=[(579, 271, 97, 114), (580, 271, 97, 114), (578, 272, 97, 114), (579, 272, 97, 114), (580, 272, 97, 114), (581, 272, 97, 114), (577, 273, 97, 114), (578, 273, 97, 114), (579, 273, 97, 114), (580, 273, 97, 114), (581, 273, 97, 114), (582, 273, 97, 114), (577, 274, 97, 114), (578, 274, 97, 114), (579, 274, 97, 114), (580, 274, 97, 114), (581, 274, 97, 114), (582, 274, 97, 114), (577, 275, 97, 114), (578, 275, 97, 114), (579, 275, 97, 114), (580, 275, 97, 114), (581, 275, 97, 114), (578, 276, 97, 114), (579, 276, 97, 114), (580, 276, 97, 114), (581, 276, 97, 114), (579, 277, 97, 114), (22, 460, 97, 114), (23, 460, 97, 114), (133, 460, 97, 114), (134, 460, 97, 114), (21, 461, 97, 114), (22, 461, 97, 114), (23, 461, 97, 114), (24, 461, 97, 114), (132, 461, 97, 114), (133, 461, 97, 114), (134, 461, 97, 114), (135, 461, 97, 114), (20, 462, 97, 114), (21, 462, 97, 114), (22, 462, 97, 114), (23, 462, 97, 114), (24, 462, 97, 114), (131, 462, 97, 114), (132, 462, 97, 114), (133, 462, 97, 114), (134, 462, 97, 114), (135, 462, 97, 114), (136, 462, 97, 114), (20, 463, 97, 114), (21, 463, 97, 114), (22, 463, 97, 114), (23, 463, 97, 114), (24, 463, 97, 114), (131, 463, 97, 114), (132, 463, 97, 114), (133, 463, 97, 114), (134, 463, 97, 114), (135, 463, 97, 114), (136, 463, 97, 114), (20, 464, 97, 114), (21, 464, 97, 114), (22, 464, 97, 114), (23, 464, 97, 114), (24, 464, 97, 114), (131, 464, 97, 114), (132, 464, 97, 114), (133, 464, 97, 114), (134, 464, 97, 114), (135, 464, 97, 114), (136, 464, 97, 114), (21, 465, 97, 114), (22, 465, 97, 114), (23, 465, 97, 114), (132, 465, 97, 114), (133, 465, 97, 114), (134, 465, 97, 114), (135, 465, 97, 114), (22, 466, 97, 114), (133, 466, 97, 114), (134, 466, 97, 114)]
srt_input=sorted(input)
mini=srt_input[0][0]
output=[srt_input[0]]
for i in srt_input:
    if i[0]<=mini+5:continue
    mini=i[0]
    output.append(i)
print(output)
---------
[(20, 462, 97, 114), (131, 462, 97, 114), (577, 273, 97, 114)]
```

you can just select the minimum, and ignore if the next one's head < selected one's head+5.
If this is not what you want, please let me know what output are you expected.

Comment: thx! this is what i wanted! works fine. need some other attachments but i can manage it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to remove duplicates, you can try this:

```
tosort = [ 5, 6, 7, 21, 5, 9, 6, 9]
seen = []
for num in tosort:
    if not (num in seen):
         seen.append(num)
print(seen)
```